# Add session for monitoring user after login using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I tried to make the monitoring session but when adding script of the model script is not running?

Login controller:

```
public function do_login(){
    $data = $this->input->post(null,true);      
    $result = $this->db->get_where('user',array('username'=>$data['username'],'password'=>md5(trim($data['password'])),))->row();
    $is_login = $this->defaults->login($result);    //load from model                                       
    if($is_login){

        $session_set = array(

            'is_login'      => true,
            'nama'          => $is_login->nama,
            'nik'           => $is_login->nik,
            'divisi'        => $is_login->divisi,               
            'jabatan_id'    => $is_login->jabatan_id,               
            'id_user'       => $is_login->id_user,
            'username'      => $is_login->username,
            'last_login'    => $is_login->last_login
        );
        $this->db->update('user',array('last_login'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),array('id_user'=>$is_login->id_user));
        $this->session->set_userdata($session_set);
        redirect('home/home');
    } else {

        redirect('login/login/index/error');
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->agent->is_browser()) {
        $agent =$this->agent->browser().''.$this->agent->version();
    } 
    elseif ($this->agent->is_robot()) {
        $agent = $this->agent->robot();
    }
    elseif ($this->agent->is_mobile()) {
        $agent = $this->agent->mobile();
    } 
    else {
        $agent = 'Unidentified User Agent';
    }

    $username = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('username'));
    $data = array(
             'namapengguna' => $username,
             'platform' => $this->agent->platform(),
             'browser' => $agent,
             'logged_in' => true,);
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @Dawid Ferenczy, thanks for correction

Comment: What is your question? what do you mean by monitoring

Comment: @IlanHasanov ,  I tried to create a login session whose function is to display or monitor any user who logs on my web. I tried to insert a script loaded from a model but not running `$is_login = $this->defaults->login($result);`